# Tableau Inventory over Time

Tags: tableau-api

I have a report that I'm trying to show in-process inventory changes over time.  I have a record with an ID, a Start Date and an End Date.  So for instance:

| ID | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1/15/2021 | 4/30/2021 |
| 23456 | 3/1/2021 | 3/31/2021 |

I'd like to be able to show a report, by month, that displays an inventory as of the beginning of the month.  Using the data above, I need to show:

| Month Beg | 1/1/2021 | 2/1/2021 | 3/1/2021 | 4/1/2021 | 5/1/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 |  | +1 |  |  | -1 |
| 23456 |  |  | +1 | -1 |  |
| Inventory | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

I don't have the ability to join 2 tables within Tableau as this procedure is restricted.  Any other ways around this?

Comment: Can you get the ability to Union 2 tables? (Easiest solution) or at least blend 2 data sources (alternate solution) or use custom (another approach)? Why and how are you restricted? License role?